# How to compare two Streams in Java 8

Tags: java, junit, java-8, java-stream

What would be a good way to compare two `Stream` instances in Java 8 and find out whether they have the same elements, specifically for purposes of unit testing?

What I've got now is:

```
@Test
void testSomething() {
  Stream<Integer> expected;
  Stream<Integer> thingUnderTest;
  // (...)
  Assert.assertArrayEquals(expected.toArray(), thingUnderTest.toArray());
}
```

or alternatively:

```
Assert.assertEquals(
    expected.collect(Collectors.toList()),
    thingUnderTest.collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

But that means I'm constructing two collections and discarding them. It's not a performance issue, given the size of my test streams, but I'm wondering whether there's a canonical way to compare two streams.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no way without coercing the streams into a collection or array as you have done above.

Comment: Ask each for an `iterator()`, and traverse them in lockstep.

Comment: BTW, this comes up in the testing framework for Streams itself.  We specified 18 traversal modes (there are more, these are the ones we tested) and traverse the "same" stream all the ways, and compare that the results are identical (modulo reorderings permitted by the stream library semantics.)  See, for example, http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/test/java/util/stream/bootlib/java/util/stream/StreamTestScenario.java.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Enum constants as test cases!?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
static void assertStreamEquals(Stream<?> s1, Stream<?> s2) {
    Iterator<?> iter1 = s1.iterator(), iter2 = s2.iterator();
    while(iter1.hasNext() && iter2.hasNext())
        assertEquals(iter1.next(), iter2.next());
    assert !iter1.hasNext() && !iter2.hasNext();
}
```

Comment: I think you may use `BaseStream<?,?> s1, BaseStream<?,?> s2` to support `IntStream`, `LongStream` and `DoubleStream` as well.

Comment: @TagirValeev -- good idea. And for the performance-obsessed, they should overload `assertStreamEquals(IntStream, IntStream)` etc.

Comment: `assertTrue` is probably better than the `assert` keyword, since it's guaranteed to be enabled (and it uses the JUnit assertion mechanism): `assertTrue(!iter1.hasNext() && !iter2.hasNext());`

Answer (score 4):

Collecting the stream under test (as you show) is a straightforward and effective way of performing the test. You may create the list of expected results in the easiest way available, which might not be collecting a stream.

Alternatively, with most libraries for creating mock collaborators, one could mock a `Consumer` that "expects" a series of `accept()` calls with particular elements. [Consume](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) the `Stream` with it, and then "verify" that its configured expectations were met.

Answer (score 4):

Using the [`elementsEqual`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#elementsEqual-java.util.Iterator-java.util.Iterator-) method in the Guava library:

```
Iterators.elementsEqual(s1.iterator(), s2.iterator())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static boolean equalStreams(Stream<?> ... streams) {
    List<Iterator<?>> is = Arrays.stream(streams)
            .map(Stream::iterator)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    while (is.stream().allMatch(Iterator::hasNext))
        if (is.stream().map(Iterator::next).distinct().limit(2).count() > 1)
            return false;

    return is.stream().noneMatch(Iterator::hasNext);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assert the stream's content *without* creating a `Stream<> expected`.

[AssertJ](https://assertj.github.io/doc/) has fluent and readable solutions for this.

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class MyTests {
    @Test
    void test() {
        Stream<Integer> actual = Stream.of(0, 8, 15); // your thingUnderTest

        assertThat(actual).containsExactly(0, 8, 15);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If order of elements doesn't matter, then comparison can be done for any number of streams using stream groupingBy() and then checking count for each element.

Example is for IntStream but you can get the idea behind this method:

```
    IntStream stream1 = IntStream.range(1, 9);
    IntStream stream2 = IntStream.range(1, 10);

    boolean equal = IntStream.concat(stream1, stream2)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity()))
            .entrySet().stream().noneMatch(e -> e.getValue().size() != 2);
```

Comment: Or even better use collect(groupingBy(identity(),counting())).values().stream().noneMatch(count -> count != 2)

Comment: This can result a false positive if one of the streams contains an element twice and the other contains none of that element. And a false negative if an element occurs more than once in each of the streams.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing the same thing:

```
static void assertStreamEquals(Stream<?> s1, Stream<?> s2) {
    Iterator<?> it2 = s2.iterator();
    assert s1.allMatch(o -> it2.hasNext() && Objects.equals(o, it2.next())) && !it2.hasNext();
}
```

Comment: What if s1 is parallel stream? ;-)

Answer (score -1):

**How to Compare Two Streams in java 8 and above: with the example of Comparing IntStream**

```
package com.techsqually.java.language.generics.basics;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class TwoStreamComparision {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String a = "Arpan";
        String b = "Arpen";

        IntStream s1 =  a.chars();
        IntStream s2  = b.chars();

        Iterator<Integer> s1It = s1.iterator();
        Iterator<Integer> s2It = s2.iterator();

        //Code to check how many characters are not equal in both the string at their Respective Position
        int count = 0;
        while (s2It.hasNext()){
            if (!s1It.next().equals(s2It.next())){
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you forget to check if the streams are of different length. Your code will crash if `s1` is shorter and give an incorrect result if `s2` is shorter.