# How to compare actual message with expected message when the lines in actual message are changing

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, string-comparison

I am trying to compare the below messages through java-selenium.But the lines are changing in the actual message during execution.Please let me know how to handle it.

Ex:

```
String expMsg="Line1.\n"
+ "Line2\n" 
+ "Line3\n" 
+ "Line4\n" 
+ Line5\n" + "\n"
+ "Line6."


String actMsg="Line1.\n"
+ "Line3\n" 
+ "Line2\n" 
+ "Line5\n" 
+ Line4\n" + "\n"
+ "Line6."
```

I tried the following but it is failing :

```
if(actMsg.contains(expMsg){
System.out.println("both the messages are same")
}
```

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved your example:

```
List<String> expMsg = Arrays.asList("Line1", "Line2", "Line3", "Line4", "Line5", "Line6");

String actMsg = "Line1.\n"
                + "Line3\n"
                + "Line2\n"
                + "Line5\n"
                + "Line4\n" + "\n"
                + "Line6.";

boolean containsAll = expMsg.stream()

                            //select only elements which are in actMsg
                            .filter(actMsg::contains) //e -> actMsg.contains(e)

                            //all strings from expMsg should be present
                            .count() == expMsg.size();


System.out.println(containsAll);
```

Split all lines from `expMsg` and check if all line are in `actMsg`.

Comment: What if `expMsg` has more different lines? You want it to return true?

Comment: @user7294900 good question. But in question is not mentioned that detail. So, I started with the idea that there is always just those line, which make other checks redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your `String`s to `Stream`s

```
Arrays.stream(actMsg.split("\n"));
```

And then [compare streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34818533/how-to-compare-two-streams-in-java-8/34818800#34818800)

Comment: I tried the below way and its failing :
 
public void verify(String expMsg, String actMsg){
Stream<String> expected=Arrays.stream(expMsg.split("\n"));
Stream<String> actual=Arrays.stream(actMsg.split("\n"));

assertStreamEquals(expected, actual);
}

static void assertStreamEquals(Stream<?> s1, Stream<?> s2)
{
    Iterator<?> iter1 = s1.iterator(), iter2 = s2.iterator();
    while(iter1.hasNext() && iter2.hasNext())
        assertEquals(iter1.next(), iter2.next());
    assert !iter1.hasNext() && !iter2.hasNext();
}



Please suggest.

Comment: Add `.sorted()` to both Streams before comparing

Answer (score 0):

AS per my understanding, the order of actualMessage does not matter, you just need to check all the expectedMessage is present in the actualMessage ? In this case save each line in a separate variable/array then verify each expectedMessage is present in actual using contains.
 `

```
for(i=1, i<6, i++) {
     if(actMsg.contains(expMsg+i){
     System.out.println("both the messages are same")
     }else 
     System.out.println("both the messages are not same")
 }
```

`

Let me know if this works