# Are stream elements sorted?

Tags: java, java-stream

Is there a way to find if the elements taken from a Stream in encounter order, are all sorted in ascending order? (The stream source could be absolutely anything, from `Arrays.stream()` to Files.lines(), for example; obviously, it would have to be an ordered stream.)

I was thinking of something like:

```
final Object[] previous_i = new Object[1];
boolean isSorted = stream
    .map(i -> {
        bool b = previous_i[0] == null || i.compare(previous_i[0]) >= 0;
        previous_i[0] = i;
        return b; })
    .filter(b -> !b)
    .findAny();
```

But this isn't quite functional style.

**Update:**

1. I'm not looking to sort the stream. Just to check if it's already sorted.
2. I'm not interested in seeing the elements of the stream. I only want to know if they're already sorted. So it's ok for this to be a terminal operation.
3. The elements are objects (not primitives) and not null.

Examples:

```
Stream<String> stream1 = Arrays.stream("a", "b", "d", "c");
boolean isSorted1 = stream1.[answer...];
assert (!isSorted1);

Stream<String> stream2 = Arrays.stream("a", "b", "c", "d");
boolean isSorted2 = stream1.[answer...];
assert (isSorted2);

Stream<String> stream3 = java.nio.file.Files.lines(Path.of(fileWithRandomContent));
boolean isSorted3 = stream1.[answer...];
assert (!isSorted3);
```

Comment: Is it okay that the stream can be consumed (which may be possible only once) or should the data still be available for future stream interactions, but now extended with additional information if the data is sorted or not?

Comment: Mostly related or boils down to [comparing two streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34818533/how-to-compare-two-streams-in-java-8), isn't it?

Comment: It is if you use `Stream::sorted`, otherwise, no, of course not.

Comment: @Progman yes, it's ok. I've updated my question.

Comment: @K.Nicholas why do you say "otherwise, no, of course not"? For example, `Stream.of("a", "b", "c")` is  not using `Stream::sorted` and yet its elements _are_ sorted, in the sense that, if you were to read them one by one (encounter order) they are guaranteed to come in sorted order because they were sorted in the source of the stream.

Comment: I don't think there is anything in the definition of stream that guarantees the order of processing. It's not an assumption you make unless you specifically use sorting functions. See, e.g., Stormcloud's answer below.

Comment: @k314159 Does the stream contains the value `null`? In case it does, what should the overall result of the `isSorted` variable be? Please [edit] your question to include several example stream values to specify the desired `isSorted` value in the different cases.

Comment: @Progman I've edited my question to clarify that the elements are all non-null objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stream's Iterator can be used for this as below:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean isSorted(Stream<T> stream) {
    Iterator<T> i = stream.iterator();
    if(!i.hasNext()) {
        return true;
    }
    T current = i.next();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        T next = i.next();
        if(current == null || current.compareTo(next) > 0) {
            return false;
        }
        current = next;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: *The stream source could be `absolutely anything`, from Arrays.stream() to Files.lines()* Unfortunately, this does not work for primitive arrays using Arrays.stream().

Comment: @WJS you are right, but that would be an IntStream, LongStream or DoubleStream and I was only asking about Stream. So this answer is indeed correct, though I would have hoped for something more succinct (preferably a single expression).

Answer (score 3):

To determine whether a `Stream` is sorted or not you should use a `Spliterator`
Here is a example:

```
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(2, 7, 1, 9);
    
    boolean isSorted = list.spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SORTED);

    System.out.println(isSorted);

    isSorted = list.stream().sorted().spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SORTED);
    
    System.out.println(isSorted);
```

The output in this case is:

```
false
true
```

You can call the method `spliterator()` on a `Stream` and on a `List` directly.

Comment: But you have to sort them first for this to work.  What if my list was `Arrays.asList(1,2,4, 5, 7, 9, 11);`?  It would naturally return false even though they are sorted in my encounter order, list or stream.

Comment: You are right, of course. The list created by Arrays.asList() is ordered, but not sorted. Spliterator.SORTED is only a flag. Returning this flag Java does not check if the elements in the list are stored in a sorted order. But if you use the sorted method on a Stream the flag will be changed to true.

Answer (score 1):

The example code provided in your answer is broken because the mapping function is stateful. See, e.g., the [Java 8 documentation on *Stateless Behavior* of streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness):

> Stream pipeline results may be nondeterministic or incorrect if the
> behavioral parameters to the stream operations are *stateful*. A
> stateful lambda [...] is one whose result depends on any state which
> might change during the execution of the stream pipeline. An example
> of a stateful lambda is the parameter to `map()` in:
>
> ```
> Set<Integer> seen = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>());
> stream.parallel().map(e -> { if (seen.add(e)) return 0; else return e; })...
> ```

The most obvious algorithm for this task checks the ordering of all adjacent pairs. For these kind of algorithms (that operate on more than one element at a time), the imperative style is usually preferable. This [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66411496/15300123) nicely demonstrates how to fluently switch to the imperative world (using the [escape-hatch operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference) `Stream.iterator()`).

With that disclaimer, let us try a functional solution just for fun.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class StreamSortChecker<T> {
    private final Comparator<T> comparator;

    private StreamSortChecker(Comparator<T> comparator) {
        this.comparator = Objects.requireNonNull(comparator);
    }

    public static <T> boolean isSorted(
            Stream<T> stream,
            Comparator<T> comparator
    ) {
        StreamSortChecker<T> checker = new StreamSortChecker<>(comparator);
        return stream
                .map(checker::wrap)
                .reduce(checker::combine)
                .map(checker::isSorted)
                .orElse(true);
    }

    private Element wrap(T minmax) {
        return new Element(minmax, minmax, (minmax != null));
    }

    private Element combine(
            Element lhs,
            Element rhs
    ) {
        boolean isUnsorted = !lhs.isSorted
                || !rhs.isSorted
                || comparator.compare(lhs.max, rhs.min) > 0;
        return isUnsorted
                ? new Element(null, null, false)
                : new Element(lhs.min, rhs.max, true);
    }

    private boolean isSorted(Element element) {
        return element.isSorted;
    }

    private class Element {
        final T min;
        final T max;
        final boolean isSorted;

        Element(T min, T max, boolean isSorted) {
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
            this.isSorted = isSorted;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "illegally relies on the encounter order" - that's the actual implication when checking if elements are sorted. I'm sure if that's illegal. For example, the Java 11 Stream methods `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` also rely on encounter order.

Comment: @k314159 You are right that the encounter-order aspect of my statement was wrong. I have edited my answer accordingly, and I have added an authorative Java-8 reference quote to underline the stateful/side-effect aspect.

Answer (score -1):

You can't assume that it's sorted (unless the documentation tells you otherwise). You can sort the stream after which it will be. What you want is:

```
stream
    .map(i -> {
        bool b = previous_i[0] == null || i.compare(previous_i[0]) >= 0;
        previous_i[0] = i;
        return b; })
    .sort()          // Added this line. You can move it around the fluent interface as needed
    .filter(b -> !b)
    .findAny();
```